# Error when posting to my backend API from React form

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, error-handling, http-post

I am creating this task tracker app using node/express, mysql, and react.

Right now I am trying to post the inputted task into my database ( I have the post route written and it works fine in postman), but when I try submitting the form from the front end of react, I am getting this error: 400 (Bad Request), and SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 js:23

My node server is running on localhost 3000 while my react application is running on localhost 3001 but I added a proxy to localhost 3000.

Below is my submitHandler code in the src of react

```
submitHandler = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault() //to prevent page refresh
        console.log(this.state)

        fetch("https://localhost:3000/api/task", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(this.state)
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
```

Below is how my backend POST route is written

```
const db = require("../models");

module.exports = function(router) {

    router.get("/api/tasks", (req, res) => {
        db.Task.findAll({}).then(data => {
            res.json(data);
        });
    });

    router.post("https://localhost:3000/api/task", (req, res) => {
        db.Task.create({
            task: req.body
        }).then(data => {
            res.json(data)
        }).catch(err => res.json(err))
    })
}
```

And my server.js file is below as well

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require("path");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const db = require("./models");
const cors = require('cors')

var corsOptions = {
    origin: '*',
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
  }
app.use(cors(corsOptions)) 

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "build")));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

app.get("ping", function (req, res) {
    return res.send("pong");
})

// app.get("*", function (req, res) {
//     res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "build", "index.html"));
// })

require("./controllers/taskController")(app);

db.sequelize.sync().then(function() {

    app.listen(PORT, () => {
        console.log("Your API server is now on PORT:", PORT);
    })

})
```

Any idea what is causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

SSL errors are generally happen when you are dealing with https://. Replace all occurences of https:// with http:// and that might solve your problem while development.

Comment: I tried doing that and then an error saying 404 not found came up

Comment: 404 signifies that URL does not exists on server. Try to hit using CURL and see if it succeeds. That way you can identify the root cause, whether it is frontend code or API code.

Comment: so I edited my post, I actually am not getting a 404 error anymore, but now I am getting a 400 error saying bad request? And that there is a synxtax error? But i don't see anything wrong with my code @gautamits

Comment: That is certainly API error. Try to use some debugger or console log at every step in API code to check where is it breaking.